# How do you bind-attr and action on the same element in handlebars?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Can you actually use two handlebar statements for the same element? for example, I have:

```
 <div class="resultRow" {{action 'didClickResultDefault' this}}>
```

But I also need to bind an id to it like this:

```
<div class="resultRow" {{bind-attr id="testID"}}>
```

Can you do both? If so, how?

Comment: What are you planning to do with the id that you bound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most certainly! What you would do is this:

```
<div class="resultRow" {{bind-attr id="testID" }} 
  {{action 'didClickResultDefault' this on='click'}}>
  {{testID}}
</div>
```

Ember allows you to bind attributes and actions to the same element. Here's a [JSBIN](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/davej/4/edit?html,js,console,output) showing what would happen if you click it.